# GROUP BY on table returning incorrect counts in MySQL with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

I am trying to return multiple counts and averages from multiple tables sorting by gender and am getting incorrect data. I understand that the following is incorrect, but I am unsure of how to fix it. (Edit: Problem with group by gender. See below.)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT c.gender AS 'Gender',
       COUNT(DISTINCT mr.mailing_recipient_id) AS 'Mailing Recipients',

  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS 'Open Total',
       AVG(CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Avg Open',

  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) AS 'Click Total',
       AVG(CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Avg Click',
       COUNT(DISTINCT ca.cons_action_contribution_id) AS Donations,
       AVG(ca.transaction_amt) AS 'Avg Donation Amt'
FROM ((mailing m
       LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient mr ON m.mailing_id = mr.mailing_id)
      LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient_click mrc ON mr.mailing_recipient_id = mrc.mailing_recipient_id
      LEFT JOIN cons_action_contribution ca ON mr.cons_id = ca.cons_id
      LEFT JOIN cons c ON c.cons_id = ca.cons_id)
WHERE m.mailing_id = 1
  AND gender IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.gender;
```

Here is the table which would be correct if the totals in the fields were correct:

```
GENDER    Mailing Recipient    Open Total    Avg Open    Click Total    Avg Click    Donations     Avg Amt
F         105                  2             0.5000      2              0.5000       105           22.5000
M         98                   2             0.5000      2              0.5000       98            18.8780
```

EDIT: Here is an example of what I am hoping to achieve. I am certain that the above values are being repeated. The below values are just examples of what I am expecting:

```
GENDER    Mailing Recipient    Open Total    Avg Open    Click Total    Avg Click    Donations     Avg Amt
F         105                  8             0.0761      4              0.0380       2             22.5000
M         98                   2             0.0204      1              0.0102       1             18.8000
```

Edit:
After playing around a bit, I thought that I had discovered that the joining the cons table was what is giving me problematic returns, but the problem is with GROUP BY when using gender. To illustrate, this query (which is grouped by mailing name instead of gender) works beautifully.

```
select m.mailing_name AS 'mailing',
COUNT(DISTINCT mr.mailing_recipient_id) AS 'Mailing Recipients',
SUM(CASE
                when mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2 THEN 1
            END)
     AS 'Open Total',
AVG(CASE
                WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS 'Avg Open',
SUM(CASE
                WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1 THEN 1
            END)
     AS 'Click Total',
 AVG(CASE
                WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) AS 'Avg Click',
 COUNT(ca.cons_action_contribution_id) AS Donations,
 AVG(ca.transaction_amt) AS 'Avg Donation Amt'
 FROM
 mailing m 
 LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient mr ON m.mailing_id = mr.mailing_id
 LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient_click mrc 
ON mr.mailing_recipient_id = mrc.mailing_recipient_id   
LEFT JOIN cons_action_contribution ca ON mr.cons_id = ca.cons_id
LEFT JOIN cons c ON mr.cons_id = c.cons_id
WHERE  m.mailing_id = 1
GROUP BY m.mailing_name;
```

The statement is identical with the exception of the first and last lines.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the (( to start your join statement.  Are you getting an error at all?..to me this should be saying no alias on a subquery as an error

Comment: and we're left open to imagine possible values for the table so that we match your output?

Comment: @Twelfth I am not receiving an error. I have ran it with and without the extra '(' and received the same results.

Comment: If you want us to help then you need to provide sample data set together with desired result set you can also set up an online demo for the ddl [@fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data in tables without this all will be suggestions only

Comment: @hjpotter92 I really do not want you to match the output as that is what is incorrect. Mailing recipient and donation should not have the same value per row. And the Open and Click totals should not have the same value per column.

Comment: This is not legal SQL.  There are 3 SELECT keywords and only one FROM keyword.  This should never run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

I'm not sure what you mean by Avg Open and Avg Click.

```
SELECT c.gender AS 'Gender',
       COUNT(DISTINCT mr.mailing_recipient_id) AS 'Mailing Recipients',

       SUM(CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Open Total',
       AVG(CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Avg Open',

       SUM(CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS 'Click Total',
       AVG(CASE WHEN mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Avg Click',
       COUNT(DISTINCT ca.cons_action_contribution_id) AS Donations,
       AVG(ca.transaction_amt) AS 'Avg Donation Amt'
FROM  mailing m
      LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient mr ON m.mailing_id = mr.mailing_id
      LEFT JOIN mailing_recipient_click mrc ON mr.mailing_recipient_id = mrc.mailing_recipient_id
      LEFT JOIN cons_action_contribution ca ON mr.cons_id = ca.cons_id
      LEFT JOIN cons c ON c.cons_id = ca.cons_id
WHERE m.mailing_id = 1
  AND gender IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY c.gender;
```

I also think that `mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 2` means open and `mrc.mailing_recipient_click_type_id = 1` mean click seems strange to me.  I would expect this data to be exclusive and stored in two different fields.

Comment: No dice. Similar output as above only mailing recipient = open total and donations by row and click total now is equal to 1 for both rows. And to answer your question, average open/click is the average number of open/click per recipient. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AnnaReed - are you sure that is not the expected value.  This is correct sql.  I suggest you post example data and expected output otherwise I doubt anyone will be able to understand your requirements.

Comment: I am certain that it isn't the expected values. When I run the queries separately, I receive different counts. It looks like values are being repeated, and I am unsure why. I suspect that it has to do with the LEFT JOINs.

Comment: @AnnaReed - We can't help unless you give us example data and expected results.

Comment: @annareed - your last comment points towards your join statements creating duplicates. Hogans code here is clean...so we are down to data issues being your problem. Change your statement here to be select * from ... (so get all fields regardless of sums/counts/otherwise). Confirm there that you are not seeing duplicate rows...if you are, start commenting out table joins until your find the join that is creating the duplicates.

Comment: I discovered the problem. I am an idiot. I need to count the mailing_recipient_id with the conditions listed above and not the conditions themselves.

Comment: @Hogan Thank you for your help thus far. After messing around a bit, I have discovered that cons is the culprit impacting my results. Do you have any suggestions in terms of how to phrase the query so that it does not return duplicate results?

Comment: I appreciate it. It turns out that the problem is in the GROUP BY statement. When I group the query by mailing name, I have no problems at all. When I group the problem by gender, I receive a table like above.

Comment: I got it! I needed to add an additional column to group by. Thanks for your patience.